# Any DC-powered, low flow-rate, inexpensive water pumps?

Tags: dc-motor, fluid-pump

Looking for small water pump, which can pump up water from a container, kept at ground-level to another container, placed 10 feet above ground. It should ideally be DC powered, and be able to transfer about 10 liters/hour.

In my search I've come across, pumps called "Rolling Pumps", and another type called "Dosing Pumps". Searching for "Rolling Pumps" brings up "Peristaltic Pumps" page on Wikipedia. Searching ebay for "Peristaltic Pump", returns "Dosing Pump" results, but not sure if they are similar. Oken Sieko (who make "Rolling Pumps") website shows a twin-diaphragm based approach.

The "aquarium pumps", I believe are all air-pumps, right ? They suck-in and pump-out air, to oxygenate the water. They are not water-pumps, right ? These seem to be fairly inexpensive.

What kind of pumps do the small table-top fountains use ?

Comment: Sounds like a screen washer pump, from any garage or junkyard...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A/C submersible aquarium pumps are designed to work underwater, why are you worried?  I've used similar pumps in fresh and salt water for years and never had one encounter an electrical failure.

I have tested [these](http://www.lightobject.com/38Lmin-Mini-DC-Brushless-Submersible-Water-oil-Pump-P396.aspx)  submersible DC pumps with fresh water and they seem to work OK. Haven't tried them outdoors yet, but they are fairly quiet in case that matters. They only claim 6.5 feet of head, but that site has other pumps that may be more suitable.

Comment: Excellent source. Thanks for the link. Looks like just what I need.

Answer (score 1):

I believe those are popularly called *fountain pumps*.

However, I believe most fountains use a [submersible pump](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Submersible_pump). The wikipedia talks about big applications, but of course the size of the application depends on the size of the pump and vice versa.

I couldn't found reference, but [this shop](http://www.discount-pumps.biz/fountain-pump.htm) says:

> All fountain pumps are submersible and have flow control.

<sup>(This is of course only guaranteed to go for their own products.)</sup>

Also, on that page are some smaller pumps, so there are smaller applications than the on the wiki mentioned oil well!

Most of these pumps are AC powered. There [sure are](http://nemosolar.com/dcsubmersiblepumps/) DC powered submersible pumps, however, I couldn't find them as small and cheap as the AC powered mentioned in the first shop.

Comment: Don't mind the pumps being AC powered, but for me AC means 230V, and submersible pump, inexpensive, plastic and AC kind-of seems a bit scary ! Will certainly look those up. Thanks for the very pertinent answer @Camil.

Comment: BTW, I do not necessarily need the pump to be submersible. I'm happy using hose / flex-pipes of necessary length, and keep the pump, high-n-dry.

Comment: You can step down the 230vac to what ever you want with a transformer..

Comment: @icarus74 most small fountain pumps I've seen are the centrifugal type. Some have fittings to mount not submersed, but if you then mount it above the water level, priming the pump may be problematic since gravity won't do it for you.

Comment: @PhilFrost why not make that an answer? ;)

Comment: Ah, the problem of "priming". Had not thought about it. Thinking a bit more about it, I think in my case, submerging is going to be a bit more problemmatic, given that most of the pumps I've seen, have a 'Max Head' spec of 0.5mtrs. So, if I submerge the pump, into a container (such as a plastic bucket) that is about 0.5mtrs deep, the pump would just cause a ripple at the top of the bucket, and wouldn't have enough pressure to pump the water out into the other container.

Comment: @icarus74 the max head spec is how high the pump can lift the water, measured from the top of the lower body of water, to the top of the higher body of water. The position of the pump relative to those bodies is not relevant. Frictional losses, from small tubing, bent tubing, etc, will reduce the maximum head. Also, more head means less current. A centrifugal pump is analogous to a voltage source: present it a low impedance and a high current will flow; present a high impedance and a low current will flow.

Comment: Excellent information there, @PhilFrost. Would've made a great answer.

Comment: @icarus74 yeah, sorry. I wanted to write a better answer, but I'm not sharp enough in physics. Basically, I think the amount of work you want to perform (lifting water 10 feet) is not possible with a "small" motor. See http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/63668/calculating-the-mechanical-power-of-a-water-pump Maybe I'll write a better answer when I've figured that out :)

Comment: Wow @PhilFrost. Respects, for the thorough approach to this. And, please give yourself some credit - I think you know your physics :-). If you check out the site (lightobject.com/...) shared by lyndon in his answer, you'd see that there are pumps (which seem to be relatively quite small), that claim to have 'Max Head' of 3mts, and one even is marked upto 6mts. Of course, if that company is selling pumps sourced from far-east, I guess they often over-spec by an order of magnitude.

Answer (score 1):

Most aquarium pumps have very high flow capacities compared to 10 l/hr however their head (height to pump water) is minimal 
My 10 usd, 25 W pump has 1800 lr/hr flow capacity and mere head of 20 cm
Seems you have a mini irrigation project in mind. (drip or flow)
If that is the case, you also need to consider UV resistance

Comment: Thanks a very interesting piece of information. Indeed, one of the longer term goals is "mini irrigation", but for the moment it is more geared towards "mini / distributed rain-water harvesting".